# Creating a PDF file which will have my 3d model [.u3d file ] in it using python with the 3d interactive tool enabled?

Tags: python, pdf, 3d, u3d

The scenario is I have to create a pfd file which will have the 3d model in it using python. For 3d model I have .u3d file. I did a bit of searching and could only find some theoretical proofs that it could be done via some libraries like pyLatex, texcaller....but I have not found any snippet which does the same [using a .u3d file and creating a pdf from it].
I am new to python.
Thankyou in advance

Comment: The requirement is such that I have to create the 3d pdf using python libraries only.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the reason is for using Python, but you can simply use Latex, and the movie15 package.

In your header:

```
\usepackage{movie15}
```

In the document body:

```
\includemovie[poster=figs/my3dmodel.png]{7cm}{6cm}{models/my3dmodel.u3d}
```

Though movie15 appears deprecated, I found it works well for embedding MP4 or U3d. An alternative is the movie9 package, which did not work for me.

If you have to use Python, you can use the PyLaTeX package, and extend it yourself with a Movie15 context.

See this example: https://github.com/JelteF/PyLaTeX/blob/master/examples/own_commands_ex.py